# Reusing Android Activities with Intent Extras

Tags: android

I have an Android application that utilizes a paid sponsor Image Button at the bottom of each activity. Touching the Image Button launches either another activity that displays the sponsor's internal (to the app) profile, or launches a Web View. Using the Web View example, I pass the URL to the Web View using the Intent's Extra parameter:

```
Intent i = null;        
i=new Intent (EventMain.this, SponsorWebView.class);
i.putExtra(URL_EXTRA, selectedSponsor.get("url"));
startActivity(i);
```

...and in the Web View:

```
url=getIntent().getStringExtra(EventMain.URL_EXTRA);
```

Clearly, the problem lies in the fact that the getIntent() function requires the calling activity, EventMain, to be hard coded in the getStringExtra() parameter list.

While this works just fine for a single activity, the sponsor bar is to appear on multiple activities in the app. I can't believe the solution is to duplicate the Web View for each calling Activity, substituting only the name of the calling Activity in the getStringExtra() parameter list.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is as follows:

In the calling class, create a static string in each class that will be launching the target activity:

```
public final static String LINK_EXTRA="LINK";
```

All other code in the calling activity remains the same:

```
Intent i = null;
i=new Intent (EventMain.this, MapView.class);
i.putExtra(LINK_EXTRA, selectedSponsor.get("url"));
startActivity(i);
```

And in the destination activity, change this:

```
link=getIntent().getStringExtra(EventMain.LINK_EXTRA);
```

to this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
link = extras.getString("LINK");
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out View.getContext(), Context.getClassLoader() and ClassLoader.getClass(String name)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext()

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getClassLoader()

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass(java.lang.String)

You can use the Context to get the name of the class, and then pass that name to the ClassLoader to get the Class object.

I should add the caveat that I've never actually done this, so there could be some unexpected snag, but from the docs it looks like a fine strategy.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Unfortunately, I am not envisioning your solution utilizing these methods. Could you please briefly outline how you see these methods working to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: I would put something like the following before "i = new Intent..."

Context c = getContext();
ApplicationInfo info = c.getApplicationInfo();
String classname = info.className;
ClassLoader loader = c.getClassLoader();
Class thisClass = loader.loadClass(classname);

and then:

i = new Intent(thisClass, SponsorWebView.class);

The only step I'm somewhat unsure of is whether c.getApplicationInfo().className will be the right name (since I've never used this myself).

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for looking at this for me. Unfortunately, this isn't going to do the trick. The problem is not with the class that is launching the Web View, it is with the Web View class itself because of the need to refer to the calling class by name in the getIntent().getStringExtra(ClassName.EXTRA) method.  I want to launch the Web View from multiple classes, and parameterizing the ClassName.extra is the sticking point. Again, many thanks for looking at my post.